# kubectl throws segmentation fault on mac

Tags: macos, segmentation-fault, kubernetes, kubectl

I have installed kubectl on a macbook (sierra 10.13.3) as per instructions here: 
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/

Install boils down to:

- curl the relevant kubectl release
- chmod +x ./kubectl
- sudo mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl

Now, if I execute kubectl I get:

`➜  ~ kubectl
[1]    1644 segmentation fault  kubectl`

However, if I go to /usr/local/bin/ and run 

`./kubectl`

everything works like it should.

Any ideas on what might be wrong here? As far as I understand the two ways of executing kubectl above should be identical?

Comment: Try "which kubectl"- there is probably another one in your PATH ahead of the one your downloaded.

Comment: Ha! I should remove my question so no one else sees it :-) Thanks!